# Loop through records in a flow and append to text to send in a single email

Tags: email, visual-workflow, loop

I'm attempting to do the following in a "Scheduled-Trigger Flow":

Send a list of Campaign Members that meet a certain criteria in a single email.

Example: John, Jane and Jared are CampaignMembers of Type contact and meet criteria X. I would like to send an email to some users with the following email body:

> Campaign members to update:
> John
> Jane
> Jared

Is such a thing possible using a loop in a flow? I can't figure out how to APPEND the name of each campaign member to some text variable which I could then reference in the body of the email.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable of text type and in the assignment use add operator this will work as concatenation of the string.

So you need to loop through all record and every time do add operation on that text variable. At the end of loop that variable will have all the name in a single variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help - is it possible to add a new line character? Or any other details on how I can format the string? Struggling to find documentation on this

Comment: Yes with that string you can add <br> tag as well. And check the checkbox of rich text email body in your template. So it will take it as a new line